# What is the purpose of this scene shown at the beginning?

Tags: plot-explanation, pet-sematary-2019

At the beginning of the *Pet Sematary* (2019) movie, there's a car parked in front of a house with one door open. There seems to be a blood trail that leads to the front door.

[image]

Then the scene transitions to Louis Creed driving with his family in the car.

What is the purpose of this scene?

Comment: It's starting the movie near the end of the story, then flashing back to the beginning of the story.  If I remember correctly, around 2/3rds of the way into the film we get back to this scene.  Similar to TV episodes that start at a crescendo then say 8 hours earlier.

Comment: [show end at the beginning](https://www.quora.com/Which-films-show-the-ending-or-a-part-of-the-ending-at-the-beginning)

Comment: Would any of the commenters care to flesh out an *actual* answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is the actual ending of the film.

In the end of Pet Sematary, Louis, Rachel, and Ellie are are all dead while Gage is locked in the car but the film does not show us what happens next.

The beginning is a hint to what has actually happened.

Comment: this is correct, it's the end of the movie showing us what happened because it cuts off at the end of the movie with gauge still in the car. We can only assume what occurred (unless we remember the beginning).